# find the differences between two csv files and mark em

Tags: python, django, csv

I'm making a website using Django ,the website allows users to upload 2 csv files , then the website will find the differences between those 2 files, print the differences and add a new "Changes" column. In that new column which will be for every record, every row gets a new "changes" or "addition" or "deletion" new record. Assuming there is no duplication. Here is views.py code so far.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import difflib
import datetime
import csv
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http import FileResponse
from .forms import FileForm
from .forms import UploadFileForm

def handle_uploaded_file(filename_1, filename_2):
    """ handle_uploaded_file is a function that takes 2 files uploaded by the users """

    with open(filename_1, newline='') as f_old:
        csv_old = csv.reader(f_old, delimiter='\t')
        header = next(csv_old)
        old_data = {row[0] : row for row in csv_old}

    with open(filename_2, newline='') as f_new:
        csv_new = csv.reader(f_new, delimiter='\t')
        header = next(csv_new)
        new_data = {row[0] : row for row in csv_new}

    set_new_data = set(new_data)
    set_old_data = set(old_data)

    added = [['Added'] + new_data[v] for v in set_new_data - set_old_data]
    deleted = [['Deleted'] + old_data[v] for v in set_old_data - set_new_data]
    in_both = set_old_data & set_new_data
    changed = [['Changed'] + new_data[v] for v in in_both if old_data[v] != new_data[v]]

    with open('difference.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='\t')
        csv_output.writerow(['History'] + header)
        csv_output.writerows(sorted(added + deleted + changed, key=lambda x: x[1:]))

def index(request): # index is a function for the upload button
    if request.method == 'POST': # POST method inserts something to the server
        print(request.FILES)
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print(form.errors)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("cool")
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES.get('file1'),request.FILES.get('file2'))
            return HttpResponseRedirect('results/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'hello.html', {'form': form})

def results(request): # results is a function that sends difference.csv back to the user once the file is ready
    file_path = (r'C:\Users\Public\Documents\PycharmProjects\filecomparison\difference.csv') #  adding an absolute path in the server, pinpoints that exact file, very important, r is to produce raw string and handle unicodeescape error
    response = FileResponse(open(file_path, 'rb'))
    response['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv' # the type of the file that will be send is .txt/.csv
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=difference.csv' # produces an attachment file for users to download called with difference in .csv file
    return response
```

Here is the old.csv

```
Name    Emp_ID  Zone_ID Zone Name   Customer Type   First Name  Cust_ID Balance Loan    Asset Name  Serial  Purchase_ID 
Jack    4145    10-34-2Z-71ABD      Bakery  Matt    41235   -123.567    123.44  43521_BLACK_BURNER  52+007XX    QOLO-LW09   
Bob 4146    10-35-2Z-71ABD      Woodsmith   Dylan   12315   -129.12 194.44  43521_BLACK_BURNER  50+001XX    KDFL-LW10   
Rick    4147    10-34-2Z-73ABD      Gunrange    Robin   64234   -134.12 133.44  43521_BLACK_BURNER  32+003XX    HFDO-LW11   
Shane   4148    10-34-2Z-72ABD      Restaurant  Aldo    31356   -121.23 949.44  43521_BLACK_BURNER  89+004XX    BDSM-LW12
```

Here is new.csv

```
Name    Emp_ID  Zone_ID Zone Name   Customer Type   First Name  Cust_ID Balance Loan    Asset Name  Serial  Purchase_ID
Jack    4145    10-34-2Z-71ABD      Bakery  Matt    41235   -123.567    123.44  43521_BLACK_BURNER  52+007XX    QOLO-LW09
Bob 4146    10-35-2Z-71ABD      Woodsmith   Ron 12315   -129.12 194.44  43521_BLACK_BURNER  50+001XX    KDFL-LW10
Jane    1234    19-35-2K-72XYZ      EO  Karen   50980   -547.95 544.39  43521_BLACK_BURNER  50+0076KK   ERQW-BN66
Shane   4148    10-34-2Z-72ABD      Restaurant  Aldo    31356   -121.23 949.44  43521_BLACK_BURNER  89+004XX    BDSM-LW12
```

Here is what should be on the difference.csv

```
Name    Emp_ID  Zone_ID Zone Name   Customer Type   First Name  Cust_ID Balance Loan    Asset Name  Serial  Purchase_ID Changes
Bob 4146    10-35-2Z-71ABD      Woodsmith   Ron 12315   -129.12 194.44  43521_BLACK_BURNER  50+001XX    KDFL-LW10   Changed
Jane    1234    19-35-2K-72XYZ      EO  Karen   50980   -547.95 544.39  43521_BLACK_BURNER  50+0076KK   ERQW-BN66   Added
Rick    4147    10-34-2Z-73ABD      Gunrange    Robin   64234   -134.12 133.44  43521_BLACK_BURNER  32+003XX    HFDO-LW11   Deleted
```

Here is what I got if I run Martin Evan's code [image: code]

Currently, I'm getting "TypeError: expected str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not list." error when I mix the codes that I had with his code. However, if I run Martin's code standalone, I got the difference.csv like the picture below, I guess `delimiter='\t'` is the cause of the "History" and "Column" got mixed up. I tried to add 2 delimiters hoping it would seperate them, but python doesnt allow me. On the other hand, after googling the solution to TypeError, I thought using open() method under handle_uploaded_file function will fix the problem, but it still persists or maybe it wasnt the right solution. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: There are additional questions to ask. What do you do if one or both lines contain duplicate rows, or if two rows have the same `Name` but different `City`s? What do you do if the order has changed?

Comment: You can have two `set`s of tuples, and `intersect` them. FIrst `s1.intersection(s2)` then `s2.intersection(s1)`.You'll then know what values are in `s1` and not in `s2` and vice-versa

Comment: @AdamSmith if there are duplicate rows, like jack, mankato in both files, that information gets skipped and hence, i didnt write it in difference.csv. If two rows have the same name but different City, then it should be printed accordingly and mark it as "changes"

Comment: @RafaelC does it still work according to what you said if I have python read the files by writing "with open('difference.csv', 'w') as outFile:" or do i have to manually input the differences in the tuple itself?

Comment: @J.Doe that's not exactly what I'm warning you about. I mean if either file has dupes, or if either file has two names at different cities. Not if they've changed between files, but if one file on its own has that sort of data.

Comment: @J.Doe we can help you with code if you provide a [mcve] (i.e post two small text blocks representing the csv and the code you are using to parse them, and not an image)

Comment: @AdamSmith if there are exactly matched dupes between 2 files, they will not be printed. If 2 names at different cities, the name from the new.csv will be printed regardless they are different people

Comment: @RafaelC i wasnt asking about the code, im in the stage where im sitting in the toilet and wondering if its possible to do so

Comment: @J.Doe Oh, ok. So the answer to this question is: *yeah*

Comment: @RafaelC I added codes to it

Comment: I agree with Rafael: the answer to the question as asked is "Yes." You still haven't addressed my concerns with the input data, and seem to be misunderstanding me. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you do not need to somehow deal with the case where `old.csv` contains duplicate entries or `new.csv` contains duplicate entries (i.e. the same name appears more than once in the same file) then as has been suggested, one way to achieve this would be to make use of Python's sets.

By making a set of the names from each file, it is then easy to determine the additions, deletions and changes using set operations. For example:

```
import csv

with open('old.csv', newline='') as f_old:
    csv_old = csv.reader(f_old, delimiter='\t')
    header = next(csv_old)
    old_data = {row[0] : row for row in csv_old}

with open('new.csv', newline='') as f_new:
    csv_new = csv.reader(f_new, delimiter='\t')
    header = next(csv_new)
    new_data = {row[0] : row for row in csv_new}

set_new_data = set(new_data)
set_old_data = set(old_data)

added = [['Added'] + new_data[v] for v in set_new_data - set_old_data]
deleted = [['Deleted'] + old_data[v] for v in set_old_data - set_new_data]
in_both = set_old_data & set_new_data
changed = [['Changed'] + new_data[v] for v in in_both if old_data[v] != new_data[v]]

with open('difference.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='\t')
    csv_output.writerow(['History'] + header)
    csv_output.writerows(sorted(added + deleted + changed, key=lambda x: x[1:]))
```

This compares whole rows for differences. Tested on Python 3.6.3

---

One problem with trying to add this script into your code is that the CSV library in Python 3.x expects the file to have been opened with the `newline=''` parameter (or in binary if 2.x is used). As your function gets already open file handles, this is a problem. Try the following:

```
import csv

def handle_uploaded_file(file_1, file_2): 
    """ handle_uploaded_file is a function that takes 2 files uploaded by the users """

    csv_old = csv.reader(file_1, delimiter='\t')
    header = next(csv_old)
    old_data = {row[0] : row for row in csv_old}

    csv_new = csv.reader(file_2, delimiter='\t')
    header = next(csv_new)
    new_data = {row[0] : row for row in csv_new}

    set_new_data = set(new_data)
    set_old_data = set(old_data)

    added = [['Added'] + new_data[v] for v in set_new_data - set_old_data]
    deleted = [['Deleted'] + old_data[v] for v in set_old_data - set_new_data]
    in_both = set_old_data & set_new_data
    changed = [['Changed'] + new_data[v] for v in in_both if old_data[v] != new_data[v]]

    with open('difference.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='\t')
        csv_output.writerow(['History'] + header)
        csv_output.writerows(sorted(added + deleted + changed, key=lambda x: x[1:]))
```

Comment: thanks for answering, it works only in sample csv files that i made same as in the picture. When i use csv files that my prof gave me and they both contain 29k records, the program gave me ", line 6, in <module>
    old_data = dict(csv_old)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 67; 2 is required" error, i wonder if i need to change "dict" to something else to make em work

Comment: You would need to [edit] your question to show a few sample lines from your CSV file that recreates the problem. Please add them as raw text, not an image. The required script change should be fairly simple. Also show what output format would be required for them.

Comment: I completely edited the question, mix the code that you gave me and mine, and showed the example of what I'm looking for, it is still in the picture, I didnt put it as raw text because I guess it is easier to understand but if you want to see it in raw text, let me know, thanks for the help sir

Comment: It is not possible to copy/paste your data from an image so it is not possible for me to easily recreate the problem and test a fix.

Comment: I added the old,new, and difference csv files on the question as a raw text

Comment: Thanks, try and make sure you preserve the delimiters e.g. commas between the fields otherwise it will not import correctly. I have also edited the script to show how it could be done with more complicated CSV files.

Comment: No, thanks for helping me sir, so far, there is no comma(",") in the files but there are "." and "+." When i run your code as a single python file, it works 100%. But, when i combined it with the code i had and changed the parameters in both with open function as fileone and filetwo, the cmd gives me "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os. PathLike object, not list

Comment: Are you able to use a service such as [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) to share a sample copy of one of the actual files? You can paste the URL that is given in a comment.

Comment: Yes, shall I copy the views.py or the csv files?

Comment: The CSV files please, so I can work out exactly what format they are.

Comment: The files you have given are tab delimited, so you need to add `delimiter='\t'` to the CSV objects. I have updated it. I'll take a look at your integration issue later.

Comment: i see, sorry i didnt realize that earlier, im also working on it in the meantime, but thank you for helping me out

Comment: Replying your last advice, do you mean I should add newline='' parameter in handle_uploaded_file function? The problem is, the file names are never going to be always "new" and "old csv, I'm integrating this in a website where users can upload their files and thus the files name uploaded will be different. I dont know how exactly to put newline='' parameter in handle_uploaded_file function with the file names that is never going to be the same

Comment: Your function appears to receive file handles, i.e. from an opened file not actual file names. Ideally the two arguments should be the two file names. Then remove your code with just my script and replace the two hardcoded filenames with the two parameters. Obviously you would then need to change how the function is called.

Comment: I thought by adding the filename_1 and filename_2 in the parameter and erase the code that I had for hadle_uploaded_file function will solve the issue but I keep getting "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile" error. Also, how do I add more than one string to delimeter function? I'm trying to seperate HistoryName into different columns

Comment: The problem is I don't have Django installed and am not able to recreate your environment. I have also assumed you are using Python 3.x? The first column is correct for my tests so I am guessing there is different issue with your environment. It might make sense to start a new question to tackle this issue.

Comment: You are right, as a standalone file, your solution works, but when im doing it in django, not so much. Thank you for guiding me through the whole process, you really help me a lot!

Comment: sorry to bother you again sir, but do you happen to know how to seperate historyname into history | name? It seems like delimiter='\t' is causing history and name mixed up, i've been trying to seperate em but i keep bumping into delimiter can only be 1 error

Comment: If you can print, I would do `print(repr(header))` to get an idea how a line is actually formatted. That would give a clue as to how to fix it.